# Adding Video and Image upload to form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

This is more of an abstract question than a specific coding issue.

I have a facebook app built using codeigniter. It's essentially just for data capture. The user completes a form that is stored in a database.

However, On the form there is the option to upload a video with their submission or upload an image. Neither of the two are compulsory, just the text fields, such as name, email etc.

My question is what is the best way to go about this? Does the user upload their video and or image before they click submit. Or on submit do i upload what ever is in the file fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] !== NULL OR $video = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'] !== NULL)
{
    if($image)
    {
       //upload image
    }

    if($video)
    {
       //upload video
    }
}

//continue sending form data regardless of above statement
```